# Python fails to run a Pyprocessing script

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyprocessing

Trying to run a basic example Pyprocessing script found [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyprocessing/) in Python 2.7, I get the following error message.  Any idea whats causing it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erez\Documents\Robin\scripts\Python\networkx-eg1.py", line 10, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyprocessing-0.1.2.7-py2.7.egg\pyprocessing\__init__.py", line 383, in run
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\__init__.py", line 123, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 135, in run
    self._run_estimated()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 164, in _run_estimated
    timeout = self.idle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 280, in idle
    window.flip()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyprocessing-0.1.2.7-py2.7.egg\pyprocessing\flippolicy.py", line 149, in flip
    currentpos = (c_int*2)(0)
NameError: global name 'c_int' is not defined
```

Comment: What's the actual code you're trying to run?

Comment: What happens if you just run python and at the python prompt, enter `from ctypes import c_int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in pyprocessing.  You are using version 1.2.7, and in that version, the file `flippolicy.py` refers to `c_int`, but that name is not defined anywhere.  In the current source code at http://code.google.com/p/pyprocessing/source/browse/trunk/pyprocessing/flippolicy.py, there is now the line `from ctypes import *`, which defines `c_int`.  The change is also in the latest version, 1.3.22.  Can you upgrade and try again?

Comment: Thanks Warren, I suspected some kind of version complication.